# How to combine two page level filters in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, dax

I want to hide all cost centers, where both values are 0. Currently, it looks like that but it doesn't really work because if one value is 0 and the other one is greater than 0 it gets hidden instead of shown.

Here is my diagram:

[image]

So if the blue bar is 0 and the other is 3 it gets hidden. Is it possible to connect both if's to avoid that? It looks like that until now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filters combine using `AND` logic rather than `OR` logic.

One possibility is to create a new measure just for filtering.

```
FilterMeasure = SUM(TableName[Act_FTE]) + SUM(TableName[Plan_FTE])
```

Put that measure in your visual filters box and require it to be greater than zero. (Make sure to clear the filters on the component pieces.)

Comment: Very nice way how to fix that. Thanks!